# Why do my regular expressions work individually but fail when I combine them?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that includes three matching groups.   The string/text that I am trying to match follows:

```
<td class="no-wrap past-rating" style="background-color: rgb(228, 254, 199);">
                    <div>
                        <b class="place">2</b><sup> 1</sup><sup class="remaining"> 1/2</sup>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        46.96
                    </div>
                </td>
```

I'm trying to match the: 2, 1 and 1/2.

I have written the following regular expressions that match the desired text on a standalone basis, but when I combine any two or all three I get know matches.

```
/(?<one>(?<=<b class="place">).*(?=<\/b>))/ matches=> 2 

/(?<two>(?<=<\/b><sup>).*?(?=<\/sup><sup class=))/ matches=> 1

 /(?<three>(?<=="remaining">).*(?=<\/sup>))/ matches => 1/2
```

Unfortunately,

```
/(?<one>(?<=<b class="place">).*(?=<\/b>))(?<two>(?<=<\/b><sup>).*?(?=<\/sup><sup class=))(?<three>(?<=="remaining">).*(?=<\/sup>))/
```

fails to match anything.   Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong and why the combined regular expression fails and the individual expression match successfully.

Comment: This has been said hundreds of times and again, Why not use an XML / DOM parser

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: If you are using interpreters such as `perl` or `python`, they have XML parsers. You haven't mentioned which language you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "combine" the regexes, you need to use a alternation operator `|`:

```
(?<one>(?<=<b class="place">).*(?=<\/b>))|(?<two>(?<=<\/b><sup>).*?(?=<\/sup><sup class=))|(?<three>(?<=="remaining">).*(?=<\/sup>))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX7gA5/1)

However, since it is HTML parts you are trying to match, I'd use a regex that is capable to deal with multiple attributes in the pattern tags, and with multiple lines inside the input text like this:

```
<b\b[^<]*class="place"[^<]*>(?<one>[^<]*)|<\/b><sup[^<]*>(?<two>[^<]*)|="remaining"[^<]*>(?<three>[^<]*(?=<\/sup>))
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX7gA5/2)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
/<b class="place">(.*)<\/b><sup>\s*(.*)<\/sup><sup class="remaining">\s*(.*)<\/sup>/
```

[Demo online](https://regex101.com/r/vL6wB1/1)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can make a simpler regex, i.e.:

```
/>\s*?([\d\/]+)\s*?<\//
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
`2`
MATCH 2
`1`
MATCH 3
`1/2`
```

---

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/dC7zR5/1

---

Explanation:

```
/>\s*?([\d\/]+)\s*?<\//gm

    > matches the characters > literally
    \s*? match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
    1st Capturing group ([\d\/]+)
        [\d\/]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \d match a digit [0-9]
            \/ matches the character / literally
    \s*? match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
    < matches the characters < literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
    m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```